# Matplotlib stacked bar only appears at every second click

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I'm currently working on a django project which allows the user to create several diagrams with matplotlib and data taken from the database.
Everything works as expected except a stacked bar which only  appears every second time the user clicks create on the site.
I have no idea why the diagram appears at first attempt and at second it only shows a plot with legend but without data.

Hope someone can help me out, this is driving me nuts...

Here is my code which creates the diagram:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import math
import pylab
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import datetime
from operator import itemgetter
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import time

class Colors(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.colors = cm.get_cmap('Blues')
        self.rcolors = cm.get_cmap('Blues_r')   
    def setColors(self, color=None):
        if color:
            self.colors = cm.get_cmap(color)
            self.rcolors = cm.get_cmap('{0}_r'.format(color))

class Diagram(Colors):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Diagram, self).__init__()
        self.plt = plt
        self.plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        self.plt.close()

class StackedBar(Diagram):
    def __init__(self, ylimit=None):
        super(StackedBar, self).__init__()
        self.ax = plt.gca()
        if ylimit:
            self.ax.set_ylim([0, ylimit])

    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:

            plots = []
            data = zip(kwargs['labels'], kwargs['x'],kwargs['y'])

            for i, d in enumerate(data):
                plots.append(self.ax.bar(np.array(d[1]), np.array(d[2]), label=d[0], color=self.rcolors(1.*i/len(kwargs['labels'])) ,align='center'))

            self.ax.set_xlabel('Date')
            self.ax.set_ylabel('Amount used')
            self.ax.xaxis_date()
            self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%d, %b, %Y'))
            plt.setp(self.ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=10, rotation=45, ha='right')
            plt.legend(plots, kwargs['labels'])
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        plt.title('\n'.join(kwargs['title'].split('|')).title())
        plt.savefig(kwargs['savepath'].format(''.join([kwargs['title'], 'sbar'])), bbox_inches='tight')
        return ''.join([kwargs['title'], 'sbar', '.png'])
```

the class StackedBar is called by djangos views.py which passes the data taken from the database to the create method. When the save function gets called it returns the filename which is used in the template to load the picture.

Here is some sample data:

```
def main():
    adict = {   'x'      : [[datetime.date(2015, 9, 19), datetime.date(2015, 9, 20)],
                            [datetime.date(2015, 9, 22)], [datetime.date(2015, 9, 21)]],
                'y'      : [[1, 2], [2], [1]],
                'labels' : [u'Test1', u'Test2', u'Test3'],
                }
    for i in range(10):
        s = StackedBar()
        s.create(**adict)
        s.save(**{'title' : 'test{0}'.format(i), 'savepath' : '/savepath/{0}'})
        del s

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and some screenshots:

on first load and on reload
[image: on load]
[image: on reload]

Why is matplotlib doing this to me? :(

Edit says: Strange thing, if i test the code in a shell it works without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Diagram(Colors):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Diagram, self).__init__()
        self.plt = plt
        self.plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        self.plt = None
```

was the solution